# How can i check if an element has got a class in it?

Tags: jquery

I  have got the below HTML as a response .

```
<div id="69" class="activateUiHTML" data-role="collapsible">
    <div class="prd-items-detials"> </div>
    <div style="" class="Topping-details" id="69">
        <section id="topping_tsection_69">
            <aside>
                <section class="secclass"><a data-id="69" topp_name="Honey with Carmel  10 ML"  class="tpActive">Honey with Carmel  10 ML</a></section>
            </aside>
            <aside>
                <section class="secclass"><a data-id="70" topp_name="Honey with Carmel  10 ML"  class="tpActive">Honey with Carmel  10 ML</a></section>
            </aside>
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to find out if any section has got class as "tpActive" ??

I wrote the below , but don't know how to check further ??

```
$('#'+v_item_id+'.activateUiHTML').find(".Topping-details").find("section")
```

could anybody please help me .

**Updated Question**

```
if($('#'+v_item_id+'.activateUiHTML').find("Toppingdetails").find("section").hasClass("tpActive")) {
   alert('has');
}else {
   alert('No');
}
```

Comment: See http://api.jquery.com/hasclass/

Comment: @Huangism, post your comment as an answer. : )

Comment: You have 2 elements with id "69". IDs should be unique.

Comment: @CaseyFalk it's a duplicate and should be closed

Comment: I think he meant how to check if element contains ANOTHER element with a class, but his question is unclear.

Comment: id has to start with a letter. You can use numbers after the first character.

Comment: @Huangism Ahh! I didn't see a duplicate tag -- my apologies.

Comment: `.find("Toppingdetails")` should be `.find(".Topping-details")` in your question update.

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) already has a native `.hasClass()` function built if that you can add to your statement.

```
if ($('#topping_tsection_69').hasClass('myClass'))...
```

Alternatively, you could add that as part of your jQuery filtering

```
$('div.Topping-details')
```

**UPDATE**

You'll need to combine the two approaches to get what you're looking for.

```
if($('#'+v_item_id+'.activateUiHTML').find("Toppingdetails").find("section.tpActive").length > 0)
```

What will happen is that your `.find()` is returning an array of the `section` items from the page. You can filter your selection with the way that I included above, or you could alternatively iterate through the elements to find what you need.

Comment: I was trying this way , updated the question

Comment: I think that part of your problem is that your initial `$().find().find()` is returning multiple objects. You'll need to iterate over that array to find all of the elements to check with `.hasClass()`.

Answer (score 0):

You spelled it out

there's [`.hasClass('className')` method](http://api.jquery.com/hasclass/) in Jquery.

or you could use [`.is('.className')`](http://api.jquery.com/is/).
whatever fits your taste.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($('.activateUiHTML').find('.Topping-details').find("section").length > 0){
    alert('found');
}
```

Comment: I need to check the class present under that section also .